# how read the data from XML file

Tags: php, xml, file

I Have a XML file which have messages and mobile number in it,i reading the XML file get values and display the values ,but now i able to display only the message but i can't able to display the mobile number.below is my code can any one guide me to do this,thanks

my Message.xml file looks like

```
[TEMPLATE] => Dear xxxxxxx, this is a message from xxxxxxx. Kindly call us regarding your appoitnment tomorrow at 9.30. 
[RECIPIENT_NUM] => 0xxxxxxxxxx
```

**php code**

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("/data/data/www/Message.xml");
print_r($xml);

echo $xml->TEMPLATE . "<br>";
echo $xml->RECIPIENT_NUM ."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: This is not a valid XML format.

Comment: thanks for your reply can you guide me how to do it.

Comment: Plaese edit your question and show the XML you are using. If you can echo the template but not the recipient_num, and do not get a error message from simplexml, there's something else going on. so please show your XML.

Answer (score 2):

The XML should look something like this

```
<xml>
  <template>Template</template>
  <recipient_num>Number</recipient_num>
</xml>
```

Just look into the tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/

Answer (score -1):

Try the following: This will turn the xml into an object so you can access the content directly.

```
$path = @file_get_contents($url);
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($path);
```

Follow the example here. 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Comment: This is what he already did. Problem lies somewhere else (xml format)

Comment: no he did not. I am getting the file content, and then I am passing a string to the actual @simplexml_load_string

Comment: Can't see any difference there. Anyways, his problems are related to the contents of the XML, not the method of loading it.

Comment: @ToBe yes i have problems related to the contents of the XML still same problem ,

Comment: @James i tried the following example its not displaying  echo $xml->RECIPIENT_NUM ."<br>";

Comment: The file you included is not an XML file. See the other answer for a sample of how XML should look like.